# Proof of minimum value of$~ax+{b\over x}~$for$~x>0~$is$~2\sqrt{ab}~$

Tags: derivatives, systems-of-equations

> Let$~a,b~$be two positive numbers. Let
> $$f(x)=ax+{b\over x}~~\text{for}~~x>0\tag{1}$$
> Show that the minimum value of$~f~$is$~2\sqrt{ab}~$

My tries for it are as following.

$$f(x)=ax+b\cdot x^{-1}\tag{2}$$

$${\mathrm{d}\over\mathrm{dx}}\left(f(x)\right)=a+(-1)b\cdot x^{-2}\tag{3}$$

$$=a-bx^{-2}\tag{4}$$

$$=\underbrace{a-{b\over x^2}>0~~\text{for}~~x>0}_{\text{too obvious from eqn1}}\tag{5}$$

$$\lim_{x\to+0}f(x)\tag{6}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to+0}\left(ax+{b\over x}\right)\tag{7}$$

$$=b\lim_{x\to+0}{1\over x}=\infty\tag{8}$$

Confusing.

Comment: At line 5, I think I made mistake.

Comment: Why do you think $a-\frac{b}{x^2}>0$? Multiplying by $x^2$ yields $ax^2=b$. Hence, $x=\sqrt{b/a}$.

Comment: Since $f>0$ is held hence thought that slope of it is positive constant without doing deep calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line five, it should have been $x=\sqrt \frac{b}{a}$ as
$$a-\frac{b}{\sqrt \frac{b}{a}^2}=0$$
thus, a minimum is attained there with:
$$f(
\sqrt\frac{b}{a})=2\sqrt{ab}$$

Answer (score 3):

You could also write it as
$(\sqrt{ax}-\sqrt{b/x} )^2 + 2 \sqrt{ab}$.
Minimum occurs at equality.
Also this is the proof of the AM-GM inequality.